# PDO lastInsertId() not working for MS SQL

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am running an insert query using PDO and then getting the newly created Id with lastInsertId(). This is all working on my localhost environment.

When I move the exact same code onto a server, the lastInsertId() is always returning blank, even though the insert statement works and inserts the new row into the database. Would this be a setting in my configuration? Any help is appreciated.

```
$insertstmt = $dbinsert->prepare($insertsql);

// bindParams ...

$insertstmt->execute();

// always blank
$id = $dbinsert->lastInsertId();

$dbinsert = null;
```

Comment: define `blank`. There is no `blank` data type, so I assume you mean one of `''`, `0`, `false`, `null`. Use [`var_export`](http://php.net/var_export) or [`var_dump`](http://php.net/var_dump) to determine which one you get. It may also help to mention what database backend (and in which version) you're using.

Comment: blank as in ''. both var_export and var_dump are returning '' as well. I am connecting to a SQL Server database using dblib.

Comment: `var_dump('')` outputs `string(0) ""`, so *are you absolutely certain* that that's what you get in ID, and not that either your code doesn't match your assumptions or that an error occurred which has been silenced in some way? If you add `echo "foo"; var_dump($id); echo "bar";` before the last line, what output do you get?

Comment: I see. I separated out that portion of code so I could test it properly. $id outputs '', var_dump outputs 'bool(false)', and var_export outputs 'false'

Comment: All this seems to tell me is that the newly inserted record is not being returned. Would this problem be caused by a different version of PDO or maybe dlib, on the server? Is there any configuration in php needed to make this work?

Comment: To help someone solve these problems, you should really post the versions of php, PDO (if not built-in), dblib, and SQL server involved. It could also be interesting whether you have autocommit turned on on your development or production machine. Does the same error occur when you're using transactions?

Comment: I ended up using a different method. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up replacing lastInsertId() by using this method: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php#105580

```
$temp = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've describe a solution for this problem on my [blog](https://blog.zajonc.pl/o-tym-jak-ozywic-metode-pdolastinsertid-podczas-uzywania-baz-mssql-i-sterownika-freetds/). I couldn't directly modify sql queries in the code, so I extended the PDO class in this way

```
class BetterPDO extends \PDO
{
    protected $stmt;
    protected $withIdentitySelect;

    public function prepare($statement, $driver_options = null)
    {
        $this->$withIdentitySelect = false;

        if (preg_match('/^insert/i', $statement)) {
            $statement = "{$statement}; select SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'Identity';";
            $this->$withIdentitySelect = true;
        }

        $this->stmt = parent::prepare($statement, is_array($driver_options) ? $driver_options : []);
        return $this->stmt; 
    }

    public function query($statement)
    {              
        $this->$withIdentitySelect = false;

        if (preg_match('/^insert/i', $statement)) {
            $statement = "{$statement}; select SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS 'Identity';";
            $this->$withIdentitySelect = true;
        }

        $this->stmt = parent::query($statement);
        return $this->stmt;     
    }

    public function lastInsertId($name = null)
    {
        $lastIndex = 0;

        if (($this->$withIdentitySelect) && ($this->stmt->columnCount() > 0)) {
            $lastIndex = $this->stmt->fetchColumn(0);
            $this->stmt->closeCursor();
        }

        return $lastIndex;
    }
}
```